# Conditionally Change BG image jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to conditionally change the background of div based on the value of a variable here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if (combo.hcs <= 10) && (combo.hcs >= 1)
            $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('BB.png')";
        else if (combo.hcs <= 20) && (combo.hcs >= 11)
            $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('BH.png')";
        else if (combo.hcs <= 30) && (combo.hcs >= 21)
            $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('BM.png')";
        else if (combo.hcs <= 40) && (combo.hcs >= 31)
            $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('HB.png')";
        else if (combo.hcs <= 50) && (combo.hcs >= 41)
            $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('HH.png')";
        else if (combo.hcs <= 60) && (combo.hcs >= 51)
            $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('HM.png')";
        else if (combo.hcs <= 70) && (combo.hcs >= 61)
            $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('MB.pmg')";
        else if (combo.hcs <= 80) && (combo.hcs >= 71)
            $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('MH.png')";
        else if (combo.hcs <= 99) && (combo.hcs >= 81)
            $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('MM.png')";
    }
</script>
```

I am not sure if this is the best approach or not but ether way, I am getting the following error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &&
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to include your two conditions inside the same brackets, like this :

```
else if (combo.hcs <= 99 && combo.hcs >= 81)
```

The complete corrected code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if (combo.hcs <= 10 && combo.hcs >= 1)
      $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('BB.png')");
    else if (combo.hcs <= 20 && combo.hcs >= 11)
      $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('BH.png')");
    else if (combo.hcs <= 30 && combo.hcs >= 21)
      $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('BM.png')");
    else if (combo.hcs <= 40 && combo.hcs >= 31)
      $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('HB.png')");
    else if (combo.hcs <= 50 && combo.hcs >= 41)
      $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('HH.png')");
    else if (combo.hcs <= 60 && combo.hcs >= 51)
      $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('HM.png')");
    else if (combo.hcs <= 70 && combo.hcs >= 61)
      $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('MB.pmg')");
    else if (combo.hcs <= 80 && combo.hcs >= 71)
      $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('MH.png')");
    else if (combo.hcs <= 99 && combo.hcs >= 81)
      $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('MM.png')");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Great that fixed it, but now i get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;"

Comment: I didn't see it first, but there's a missing closing bracket in your instructions, before the `;`. You need this : `$(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('MM.png')");`

So add the bracket in every instruction and you're good to go. I suggest you take a look at Jimmie Johansson answer below if you want to improve your code even further.

Answer (score 3):

I think my approach would be to save the background-urls in an array.

```
var imgs = ['BB.png','BH.png']; // etc in right order

var myIndex = Math.floor(combo.hcs/10);
$(".myClass").css("background-image", "url(" + imgs[myIndex] + ")");
```

With this solution you would not need the if/else statements. For every tenth, you store an img-name in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a switch statement and a more concise approach to remain DRYer and cleaner:

```
  var bg;
  var x = combo.hcs;

switch (true) {
   case (x>0 && x<=10):
     bg = "BB";
     break;
   case (x>10 && x<=20):
     bg = "BH";
     break;

// etc....

}

$(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('" + bg + ".png'");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ask for a different solution, I would actually do it in a generic way. I would name images like 10.png, 20png, 30.png... 100.png

and then would load them something like this:

```
var imageName = Math.ceil(combo.hcs/10)*10
var imageFullName = imageName+'.png'
$(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('"+imageFullName+"')";
```

you will edit it but I hope you got the point, this has only 3 lines. You can also add conditions for boundary dimensions.

And about your error:
your code

```
if (combo.hcs <= 10) && (combo.hcs >= 1)
```

should be like this:

```
if ((combo.hcs <= 10) && (combo.hcs >= 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be closing the brackets. The brackets enclose the condition:

```
if (combo.hcs <= 10 && combo.hcs >= 1)
        $(".myClass").css("background-image", "url('BB.png')";
```